# Enterprise firewall block specific brower (Firefox)

Tags: firewalls

Apparently, some enterprise firewalls can block specific browsers. I have an example of one blocking all browsers except the ones based on chromium recent versions (Chrome and Edge work) but Firefox is blocked (with a message when loading any page).

Knowing that user-agent switching does not unblock Firefox, I was curious to know how it was performed. I tried to look at the developer mode but could not find anything.

Do you have any clue?

Comment: Which firewall? Is there a client agent from the firewall installed on the endpoint?

Comment: I don't know which firewall. And I don't think there is one the client side. I'm thinking maybe the filter can happen on the HTTP packet? TCP packet? Certificate? Or maybe some advanced recognition with javascript / browser functionalities,...

Comment: How do you know it's the enterprise firewall? We are going to need confirmation of your assertions and more technical details.

Comment: Given the lack of information it is unclear what information are actually used. One can only speculate. If it is not the User-Agent header it might be the TLS fingerprint (JA3) which is the same for Chromium based browsers which all use BoringSSL as TLS backend, but is different from others, i.e. Firefox uses NSS. It might also some script running inside the browser on first connect, which decides based on the capabilities of the browser.

Comment: I know it is the enterprise firewall because it returns a webpage explaining the blocking of the browser. I strongly suppose it is indeed, no 100% confirmation

Comment: Screenshot? Other details? We're in the dark here.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot. I was more interested by the theory of it anyway. Assuming it is not a .exe detection or user-agent, I was assuming other means were usable to identify through the network activity / signature.

Comment: You can probably circumvent this either way by tweaking with Firefox settings/flags if I'm correct.

Comment: is there a way to log all the requests and responses from when I hit enter to go to a website and the denial. And then do the same with Edge to compare both logs and see where it triggers?